# Removing a playlist from iOS MPMediaLibrary

Tags: swift, apple-musickit, mpmedialibrary

MPMediaLibrary contains the api for creating a new playlist:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary

```
func getPlaylist(with uuid: UUID, creationMetadata: MPMediaPlaylistCreationMetadata?, completionHandler: @escaping (MPMediaPlaylist?, Error?) -> Void)
```

But it does not contain an api for removing the playlist. How is that action performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from Apple tech support which confirms this is by design.